# finite index subgroups in free group non-trivial intersection with each of the non-trivial subgroups of the free group.

Tags: group-theory, covering-spaces, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I was reading a paper and find this statement in the abstract, "If $H$ has finite index in $F_m$, then $H$ has non-trivial intersection with each of the non-trivial subgroups of $F_m$" where $F_m$ is a free group of rank m. The author claims that it's a obvious statement but I don't see how. All I know is, as $[F_m:H]<\infty$, $H$ is finitely generated and free(being subgroup of a free group $F_m$).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's true and somewhat immediate in arbitrary torsion-free groups. More generally in a group the intersection of an infinite subgroup with a finite index subgroup is infinite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M$ be the core of $H$; then $[F_m:M]=k\lt \infty$. Let $K$ be any nontrivial subgroup, and let $x\in K$, $x\neq e$. Then $x^k\in K$ is nontrivial, but has trivial image in $F_m/M$, since the order of $F_m/M$ is $k$. Thus, $x^k\in K\cap M\subseteq K\cap H$. Hence $K\cap H$ is nontrivial, as claimed.

Comment: Thanks for a quick solution. I was wandering where did you use that fact that group $F_m$ is free?

Comment: does the result still holds even when the group is not free?? @Arturo Magidin

Comment: @Infinity: Well, I used the fact that $F_m$ is torsionfree; if you don’t know that the group is torsion free, then $x^k$ could be trivial. But other than that, I don’t think you need to assume the groups are free.

Comment: alright, that makes lot more sense now! thanks!

Comment: I was wandering, does the result still holds for infinite index subgroups of free group? May be I am wrong, just a wild guess

Comment: @Infinity: No. If $m\gt 1$, take the subgroup generated by one free generator, and then the subgroup generated by a *different* free generator.

Comment: oh yeah, like in $F_2=<a,b>$, $<a>\cap <b>=e$.